# CoreData+CloudKit activity import crash (iOS 14)

Tags: core-data, cloudkit, ios14, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

Very soon after launch CoreData+CloudKit (NSPersistentCloudKitContainer) crashes by throwing this exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Must register a handler for activity identifier "com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.activity.import." before submitting it'
> terminating with uncaught exception of type CKException

I can't seem to find any documentation on handlers needed for activity imports. I am guessing this is an iOS 14 bug???

Answer (score 1):

It is. I have the same error. On Simulator works great while on Device crashes.  My guess is a problem CloudKit and the Persistent Store. They need fix this.